Deep cluster-specific feature selection?
As the title states, I was wondering if work exists on achieving feature selection based on the cluster the datapoint belongs to (e.g. each cluster has a different set of selected features).I know this has been done for shallow methods, but has it been done for deep clustering methods?
Thanks
